# Hadoop cluster - Hive can not start after reboot

Tags: hadoop, hive, centos, cluster-computing

I have hadoop cluster of 5 nodes running. 
Hive was running fine and could create tables, add data etc.
Then tried rebooting all 5 nodes and now Hive can not start. 
Using MySql as Metastore.
What could be the issue and how to fix it? Logs when trying to start `hive`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:689)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:628)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:529)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:209)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1528)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, use local Hive Metastore for Spark Thrift Server by adding the following property under /etc/spark/conf/hive-site.xml:

```
 <property>
 <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
 <value>thrift://localost:9083</value> 
 </property>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it is.